# Regex to find combination of lines not containing a string

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find the correct regex that, within this input:

```
@Tag-1234
Scenario:
Blabla

Scenario:
Blabla

@Tag-1234
Scenario:
Blabla
```

Will select only the second one (the one without a tag).
So far I tried something like `(?!@Tag-\d{4})\nScenario`, but it's not doing the trick.

Can anyone throw some light into this?

I'm doing my tests on regex101 -> https://regex101.com/r/msDHKf/1

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems I was missing the \n before the tag that would concatenate to the search, so the regex would be

```
\n(?!@Tag-\d{4})\nScenario
```

So close!

Answer (score 0):

In the pattern `(?!@Tag-\d{4})\nScenario` the lookahead can be removed as it is directly followed by matching `\nScenario` so the assertion will always be true.

If there should be no tag before Scenario but a newline, you can just match 2 newlines and then Scenario

```
\n\nScenario\b
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HH06iT/1).